# Jupyter notebook not reading my 'SMILES' to make Morgan Fingerprints

Tags: rdkit, fingerprinting, cheminformatics

I am trying to make a morgan fingerprint. I have the file upload however when I try to have the code read the SMILES it tells me there is a problem with understanding them.

Here is my code:

```
# Function to generate morgan fingerprints from SMILES
def generate_morgan_fingerprint(smiles):
    mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles(smiles)
    if mol: 
        fp=AllChem.GetMorganFingerprintAsBitVect(mol,2,nBits=2048)
        return list(fp)
    return [0]*2048

#Read the CSV file
df = pd.read_csv('/Users/Desktop/trainining_data.csv')


#Provide the input data part 2


#Define 'activity' as 'activity' column in the dataframe
activity=df['activity']

#Display the first few rows of the activity column
print(activity.head())

#Define 'SMILES' as the 'SMILES' column in the dataframe
smiles = df['SMILES']

data = {'SMILES','activity'}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

# Calculate Morgan fingerprints
df['morgan_fp']= df['SMILES'].apply(generate_morgan_fingerprint)
X=np.arrayy(df['morgan_fp'].to_list())
y=df['activity'].values
```

I have already tried to change df['SMILES'] to smiles and that did not work. I've excluded data, and df, both of which did not help.

Comment: Could you please provide the exact error/warning message you get running this code?